# Springboot hasAnyRole allow all/any roles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I have an endpoint that I have to expose to all roles, whoever has at least one of the roles should get access to the api.

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')")
```

Now that the number of roles is increasing i have to add all the new roles to the API. Is there any way to expose everyone who have any role without specifying everyrole here?
I am expecting something like this

```
   @PreAuthorize("hasAnyValidRole()")
```

Comment: The following could be an option for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904626/annotation-based-securing-endpoint/70913302#70913302  in your case the annotation name would be something like `BasicAccess` (or similar). Everytime you need to include a new role, will be enough adding it only in such annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a quite easy solution.

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can directly do it from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, override the method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` and don't use PreAuthorize annotation

you may simple write

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.antMatcher("your end point here").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

this will allow any authenticated user to access that URL

Hope this Helps !

Comment: This way i will have to edit `ApiSecurityConfig` each time a new API is introduced. I would prefer if I could do this in the controller.